# Tensorflow: Could not find matching concrete function to call loaded from the SavedModel

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, random-forest

I'm trying to save and load a model across two files.

in file 1:

```
rf = tfdf.keras.RandomForestModel(task=tfdf.keras.Task.REGRESSION, verbose=1, num_trees=318, max_depth=20)
rf.compile(metrics=["mse", "accuracy", 'mae'])  # Optional, you can use this to include a list of eval metrics
rf.fit(x=train_ds)
rf.save_("./model/tfdf_model")
```

in file 2:

```
 loaded_model = tf.keras.models.load_model("./model/tfdf_model")
    ...
test_ds = tfdf.keras.pd_dataframe_to_tf_dataset(
    test_data,
    task=tfdf.keras.Task.REGRESSION)
    preds = loaded_model.predict(test_ds)
```

I keep having this error:

```
ValueError: Could not find matching concrete function to call loaded from the SavedModel. Got:
      Positional arguments (2 total):
        * {'TotalFloors': <tf.Tensor 'inputs_7:0' shape=(None,) dtype=float32>,
     'Total_Amenities': <tf.Tensor 'inputs_27:0' shape=(None,) dtype=int64>....
```

I've tried serializing the model with joblib, pickle, installed tf-nightly (as suggested here [Could not find matching function to call loaded from the SavedModel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58575586/could-not-find-matching-function-to-call-loaded-from-the-savedmodel))

My end goal is just to be able to load a model that was trained and predict new incoming data, if there's another solution I'd be glad to hear it!
I can also provide the full error message if needed.